# For multipart request, how to use using @ModelAttribute and Hashmap together?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

First of all, thank you in advance for your support.

My problem;

First I am successfully getting my specific parameters in Employer. However, I also have a constantly changing parameter list in request. I want to get them with Map too.

My dto:

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private MultipartFile document;
}
```

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/employee", method = POST, consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public Mono<Employee> saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee, Map<String,Object> otherValues) {
System.out.println(otherValues.get("key1").toString());
return employeeService.save(employee);
}
```

I attached a request example aslo.

NOTE:
I used @RequestParam, @RequestPart before Map<String,Object> otherValues like this;

```
 @RequestParam Map<String,Object> otherValues
 @RequestPart Map<String,Object> otherValues
```

But I still couldn't get the rest of the data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get values from form data, you can create a model like a DTO, with field of both entity (employee) and additional data (otherValues). Because `@ModelAttribute` can bind data to only one named model attribute

Answer (score 0):

This is working for **Spring MVC**. But When you work with Spring **WebFlux** for **reactive applications**, it doesn't work.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/employee", method = POST, consumes ={MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public Employee saveEmployee(
@ModelAttribute Employee employee, 
@RequestParam Map<Object,Object> otherValues,
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
System.out.println(otherValues.get("key1").toString());
return employeeService.save(employee);
}
```

Main trick is to use Object for key and value;

```
@RequestParam Map<Object,Object> otherValues
```